# Listings - ignore keyword within String

Tags: listings

I'm using Listings, and want keywords to be ignored if they are within Strings. For example, the code in my example highlights `if` within the String:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

%define Javascript language
\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break},
  keywordstyle=\color{niceblue}\bfseries,
  ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this, return},
  ndkeywordstyle=\color{purple}\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  sensitive=false,
  comment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  commentstyle=\color{pink}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{darkyellow}\ttfamily,
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
}
 
\lstset{
  language=JavaScript,
  extendedchars=true,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showspaces=false,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize,
  numbersep=9pt,
  tabsize=2,
  breaklines=false,
  showtabs=false,
  captionpos=b,
  upquote=true,
}


\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}[language=JavaScript]
console.log("lorem if ipsum");
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

I tried
`morestring=**[d]{'},`
as I had seen recommended, but this did not change anything.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Normally, the keywords you use should do (so `morestring=[b]"`). If you'd use `morestring=*[b]"` you'd get the behaviour you're describing (keywords being highlighted).